# WCF - x509 Certificate from Smart Card - 'Cannot Verify Signature'

Tags: wcf, iis-6, pki, wshttpbinding, x509certificate2

I have a WCF service running on IIS6 which is configured with a WSHTTPBinding using the "Transport with Message Credentials" security setting (with the transport client credentials set to 'None' and the Message set to 'Certificate'.  This is being consumed by a .NET client that was created through the auto generated code by consuming a service in VS 2010.

In my development environment, I created a certificate to act as both the service cert and the IIS SSL certificate, and since I was lazy, I exported the certificate for use with my client application.  Everything works great in that configuration, but that is not the target environment.  The idea is to have users utilize their smart cards to access this service.  The server will not be on the same domain and LDAP is not allowed, for now.

The problem is that now I got this in a test lab and set up an environment where the SSL certificate was issued by the same CA as the user's certs, and I have created a custom x509 Cert validator and service credentials, but after the initial call to my validator, something is happening in between the hand off and kicks out an error on the service trace log saying, "Error verifying message security" with an inner exception of "Cannot verify the signature".  Since is is coming through my custom validator and I got the message logging up, everything looks fine on the SOAP side and I am getting the certificate through on the other side.  I have made sure that every cert that I am trying to use is in the "Trusted Users" store and even tried exporting the certs and putting them in the local computer "Personal" store, with no luck.

I have a feeling that I do not fully understand the use of the service certificate and the client certificate in the web.config file.  Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have managed to answer my own question with some help from my coworker.  After we sat down together and started to run a bunch of questions by me and doing some random google searches, we decided to change something in the configuration that surprised me.

So to finish my question up top, I had the message credentials set to "Certificate" with the encryption algorithm suite set to "TripleDesSha256Rsa15".  Turns out that the certificates on the smart card, or the card itself, would only support Sha1 (which was not an option with everything else).  When we changed the setting to "Basic256", everything started working.  I eventually was able to set it to "TripleDesRsa15" and it continued to work.

Basically, WCF sends the certificate up without a private key, because it cannot access it with that encryption algorithm.  WCF ***DOES NOT*** throw an exception with this when trying to access the certificate, it will only throw it on the server side with the exception "Could not Verify Signature".  Kind of wish it would say "There was no signature" because that would have been a bit easier to track down.  I don't know if anyone will ever find this useful, but if you do and can find a reference to the "Proper" way of using Smart Cards with WCF, please post it with a ref.

Overall, check your encryption algorithm that you are trying to use, and make sure it works with the smart cards/certificates that you plan on using.